# form reset that also submits

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
<form id="form-lecturerInfo-setup">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>

<script>                
$('#form-lecturerInfo-setup').submit(function(event){
...
});
</script>
```

When form is submitted I serialize its data and submit them to a database. 
When reset is hit the form inputs are reverted to what they contained earlier (normal).

What I want to do is that when reset is clicked, the default behavior happens (as explained earlier) but then I also want the submit behavior to happen, so that the old form info are resubmitted to the database.

Doable?

Comment: I rolled back a revision that was simply adding the given answers to this question to the question.  Please, accept answers, do not modify your questions to include their answers after given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the reset button. Have it call the `reset()` method of the form object, then call its `submit()` method.